# Angular Material Theming - $mdThemingProvider is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm uisng Angular Material and now I'd like to change default theme to use the others paletts as follow:

```
config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
          .primaryPalette('brown')
          .accentPalette('red');
```

But I'm getting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined
```

How this could be fixed?
P.S. It seemed this issue from version 0.7.0 and still not fixed.

Comment: make sure you have 'ngMaterial' injected to your Angular app

Comment: It is - default theme are working fine.

Comment: I tested it locally it works fine, can you put your sample on jsfiddle or somewhere where we can see,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed in config:

```
config(["$routeProvider", "$mdThemingProvider", function ($routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
```

Comment: Can you point me where to find a complete bootstrap + custom theme example?